# google play "Depends on menu Your app depends on having a “Start,” “Select,” or “Menu” button to reach the menu" error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-tv

I have xamarin android project. I want to release that app to google play as tv app but google play always produce error like below:

> Depends on menu: Your app depends on having a “Start,” “Select,” or
>   “Menu” button to reach the menu. Android TV controllers do not support
>   a “Select,” “Start,” or “Menu” button. Please refer to our Gamepad
>   Button Presses documentation for details:
>   http://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html#buttonProcess

on shared link, talking about game-pad. I did not understand what the error means. Is google play detect my app as Game ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's just telling you that TV apps must support gamepad input

Comment: I added that but I got same error

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: i don't remember exactly but you need to add long click event in order to make your app accessable by a button